# choosing the right pattern to use when initializing pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm confused to determine what is the different between these two
struct initialization.

1.

```
a_struct_t *create_a_struct(int a, char *b);
void destroy_a_struct(a_struct_t *a_struct);

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
} a_struct_t;

int main()
{
    a_struct_t *a_struct = create_a_struct(1, "FOO");
    destroy_a_struct(a_struct);
    return 0;
}

a_struct_t *create_a_struct(int a, char *b)
{
    a_struct_t *a_struct = malloc(sizeof(*a_struct));
    a_struct->a = a;
    a_struct->b = b;
    return a_struct;
}

void destroy_a_struct(a_struct_t *a_struct)
{
    free(a_struct);
}
```

2. 

```
void a_struct_init(a_struct_t *a_struct, int a, char *b);

typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
} a_struct_t;

int main()
{
    // from heap
    a_struct_t *a_struct = malloc(sizeof(*a_struct));
    a_struct_init(a_struct, 1, "FOO");
    free(a_struct);

    // from main stack
    a_struct_t a_struct;
    a_struct_init(&a_struct, 1, "FOO");
    
    return 0;
}

void a_struct_init(a_struct_t *a_struct, int a, char *b)
{
    a_struct->a = a;
    a_struct->b = b;
}
```

I have seen plenty of c codes use both patterns.
my questions is what is the best pattern to use
when initializing a struct using both patterns
and is there any pros and const between them?

Note: In the second main function, I use two initialization
one from heap and one from stack.

Comment: Neither.  Both load the malloced struct with a pointer to the passed char array, so leaving the lifetime of the struct tied to the lifetime of the string.  That is a very bad idea and can lead to nasty heizenbugs, especially if the struct is used for, say, inter-thread comms.  MALLOC/STRCPY the char array.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I'm sorry, i have edited my question

Comment: The advantage of the first pattern is that it keeps the memory management in a single isolated part of the code. That can simplify error handling (which is missing in your examples). And is simplifies porting code to systems where using `malloc` is not an option. For example, an embedded system may only support memory allocation using a [memory pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool).

Answer (score 1):

The first method (factory method returning pointer to new object) is more consistent with OO design, combining creation and initialization, so that an object can't be created without being initialized properly, and no object can be initialized twice.

The second method is more old-school, just passing a pointer to an init method. This is more flexible if you want to have different init methods for the same type of object, or if you want to be able to re-initialize an object.

The choice is up to you based on what you want to accomplish and how you want to communicate your intent.

Comment: Both dynamic allocation schemes are dangerously flawed:(

Answer (score 1):

*I'm confused to determine what is the different between these two struct initialization.*

In simplest terms, The differences (in the parts of interest anyway) are that one construct *returns* a `struct *`, the other *outputs* a  `struct *`.  Both are valid, useful methods, and when used properly are perfectly sound.  The method that *returns* a `struct *` is very useful for (but not limited to) creating an instance of a struct on the heap.  The method that *outputs* a `struct *` is more commonly used for (but not limited to) updating the contents of an already existing `struct.` (Whether created on the heap, or on the stack.)

In your examples neither method shown will work as written.  i.e. modifications for both are necessary before either are safely usable.  And, if modified, both can be made equally useful, depending on what the coder intends.

Note also that the only part of `a_struct_t` that *needs* allocated memory (at least for the second method), is the member `char *b;`, but is allocated in neither of your examples.  So, to initialize either example requires that `char *b` be allocated.

The First example requires that you return a pointer, and for that pointer to to accommodate storing values before being returned, also requires that it be allocated memory.  Then again, as in the second example, the member `char *b` also requires an additional memory allocation.

The following example covers ***both*** of your examples. demonstrating that each work equally well (IMO),   Only on your style, application needs, etc. determine which method is used:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
} a_struct_t;

//method 1
a_struct_t * a_struct_init_B(int a, char *b);

//method 2
void a_struct_init(a_struct_t *a_struct, int a, char *b);

int main(void )
{
    // created on stack
    a_struct_t a_struct;    
    
    //method 2
    a_struct_init(&a_struct, 1, "FOO");
    free( a_struct.b);
    
    //method 1
    a_struct_t *pA_struct = a_struct_init_B(2, "Foo2");
    if(pA_struct)
    {
        //use it here, then free
        free(pA_struct->b);
        free(pA_struct);
    }
}

void a_struct_init(a_struct_t *a_struct, int a, char *b)
{
    a_struct->a = a;
    a_struct->b = malloc(strlen(b)+1);//+1 room for nul terminator
    if(a_struct->b)
    {
        strcpy(a_struct->b, b);
    }
}

a_struct_t * a_struct_init_B(int a, char *b)
{
    a_struct_t *pA_struct = malloc(sizeof(*pA_struct));
    if(pA_struct)
    {
        pA_struct->a = a;
        pA_struct->b = malloc(strlen(b)+1);//+1 room for nul terminator
        if(pA_struct->b)
        {
            strcpy(pA_struct->b, b);
        }
    }
    return pA_struct;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the string in the struct (not only the reference to it) I would rather:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int a;
    char b[];
} a_struct_t;


a_struct_t *a_struct_init(a_struct_t *a_struct, int a, char *b)
{
    if(!a_struct)
    {
        a_struct = malloc(sizeof(*a_struct) + strlen(b) + 1);
    }
    if(a_struct)
    {
        a_struct->a = a;
        strcpy(a_struct->b, b);
    }
    return a_struct;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some points that your example doesn't bring out:

You can't use the second version if you want to return the structure from the place where it's defined, since returning the address of a local variable is UB. Since in your example it all happens in main, this question doesn't arise.

If you might have an array of structures, then while you can allocate the array either on the heap, or 'on the stack', you need to initialize the array elements somehow, so I think its better always to have separate allocation and initialization routines.

If your structure were to itself have allocated pointers, then you need to have a routine to free these. Again, to deal with array elements, I think its best to have a 'empty_a_struct' routine as well as a 'destroy_a_struct' (which I would call 'free_a_struct').

Comment: I should have said defined instead of created I guess. I meant to make the obvious point that local variables have limited scope,

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in dynamically allocated individual structures then the first alternative, with a combined allocation / initialization function, has at least these advantages:

1. It's easier and cleaner to use.
2. It can be used in conjunction with opaque types.

Otherwise, however, the second alternative, with a dedicated initialization-only function, has some important advantages:

1. It can be used on objects with automatic or static storage duration.
2. It can be used iteratively to prepare the elements of an array of structures.

Furthermore, note that **the two are not mutually exclusive**.  It is entirely reasonable to provide both functions, especially if the allocating function relies on the initialization-only function for setting the contents of the object.  That's true even if you are providing for an opaque type.

Additionally, do understand that the need for a tear-down function is unrelated to which approach you take to setting up instances.  If all you need to do is free the structure (and you're willing to commit to that going forward), then you don't need such a function.  On the other hand, if some sort of cleanup of the members is required as well then a teardown function is appropriate no matter which approach you take to setting up instances.  Details, such as whether the function actually frees the structure, might vary between the two alternatives, but whether a teardown function is appropriate is its own consideration.